# Echo a Variable."_string" (concatenated with a string)

Tags: php, string, variables, concatenation

Hi Guy's any idea on how to make this work?

```
<?php $themename_orig = get_bloginfo ( 'name' );
      $clean = toAscii($themename_orig);
      $shortname_opciones = $clean;
?>
body { 
background:url("<?php echo $shortname_opciones."_bg_img"; ?>") no-repeat scroll center top 

<?php echo $shortname_opciones."_color_bg"; ?>; 
}

#logo 
{ 
background: url("<?php echo $shortname_opciones."_logo"; ?>") 0 17px no-repeat; 
}
```

Basically my problem is that I need to echo a variable after concatenating it with a string, that variable does exist.

Comment: It is extremely bad style to get variablenames from other variables. I really, really recommend you use an associative array (or better - though more complex - an object) for this. It _will_ save you a lot of trouble later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ${$shortname_opciones."_bg_img"};
```

Comment: I honestly don't know if i should +1 or not, since it's the correct answer but still a bad solution for a simple problem that wouldn't exist if he did the right thing in the first place.

Comment: @dbmerlin how do you suggest it should've been done?
the variables are created xxvar = shortname."_bg_img" in the backend
then called on the front end with this solution. 

If you got a better way of creating lot's of variables that start with the same shortname + a suffix enlighten me I'm sure there is but I don't know it.

Comment: @Dario: With either an object or an associative array.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio I will look that up and see if I can apply it on the project (I'm not an advanced PHP coder but love to learn :D ) So thanks a lot for the answer and for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
background:url("<?php echo $shortname_opciones; ?>_bg_img")
```

Comment: This would print variablecontent_bg_img But variablecontent_bg_img is a variable it self and that is what I need to get.